# After .csv export items in one cell only

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Having the following:

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]'):
            yield{
                'name': entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()').extract()
            }
```

I want to extract names of users on a single page, however after .csv export names are in one cell. How to change that? What is the most appropriate method?

I am saving files as csv by simply adding `-o file.csv` when running the crawler.

Output i receive is in row number 1.

[image]

Output I want is more or less like in rows from 3 to 5.

**Please further explain why this question deserves a down vote? To improve quality of my questions i want to be aware of that.**

Comment: What is the code for saving to csv?

Comment: You have to provide a [mcve]. Your question is off-topic without one.

Comment: Question updated please inform me if anything needs to be added to make this question more complete. Appreciate your advice

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what to improve?

Comment: Your code defines a class, but it doesn't do anything. Consider providing a snippet that people can run. Also, make sure you provide observable facts that don't require interpretation. Your "names are in one cell" is bad in that context, just show the output and the expected output.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt added screen shots difficult to provide working snippet as you need to have scrapy installed to make it work. I am hardly a python expert but i do not think it is possible to provide fully functional code snipper without having a scrapy framework installed.

Comment: Well, installing scrapy is hardly difficult, I guess. However, are you sure it is even relevant? Is your difficulty with scrapy or is it with writing the obtained data to disk? If it is the latter, replace the call to scrapy with just the data it returns to get closer to the heart of the issue.

Comment: It is not difficult, but without it snippet will not work. Problem is scrapy specific and the way it process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()').extract()
```

is actually a list of names.

Try iterating over it and yielding one item for each name:

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]'):
            for name in entry.xpath('.//tr[@class="row"]/td/p/a/text()').extract():
                yield {'name': name}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!